# Edit, save, self-modifying HTML document; format generated HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, self-modifying

Motivation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120689/create-self-modifying-html-page-on-box

Bug: String escaping , formatting `html` , `js` generated by initial edited , saved `html` , `js`

e.g.,

a) if open "saveFile.html" at local browser ;

b) type "abc" into `textarea` ;

c) click `save file` button ;

d) click `Save` at `Save File` dialog ;

e) `file-*[date according to universal time].html` saved to disk ;

f) open `file-*[date according to universal time].html` in browser ;

g) type "def" into `textarea` ;

h) repeat d) , e) , f) ;

i) Bug: result at second `file-*[date according to universal time].html` does display `textarea` containing "abc def" text content ;  `button` *not* displayed at `html`:

```
// at rendered `html` from second `file-*[date according to universal time].html`
// `textarea` containing "abc def" displayed here , 
// `button` _not_ displayed ; following string displayed following `textarea`:
');"console.log(clone);var file = new Blob([clone], {'type':'text/html'});a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);a.download = 'file-' + new Date().getTime() + '.html';a.click();};
```

generated at line *26* , "saveFile.html"

```
+ "var clone = '<!doctype html>'+ document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(/<textarea>.*<.+textarea>/, '<textarea>'+document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value+'<\/textarea>');"
```

---

"saveFile.html" v 1.0.0

html , js

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- saveFile.html 1.0.0 2015 guest271314 edit, save `html` document -->
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea>
</textarea>
<button>save file</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var saveFile = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
var a = document.createElement("a");

saveFile.onclick = function(e) {

  var clone = ["<!doctype html><head></head><body><textarea>"
              + input.value
              + "</textarea>"
              + "<button>save file</button>"
              + "<script type='text/javascript'>"
              + "var saveFile = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];"
              + "var input = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];"
              + "var a = document.createElement('a');"
              + "saveFile.onclick = function(e) {"
              + "var clone = '<!doctype html>'+ document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(/<textarea>.*<.+textarea>/, '<textarea>'+document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value+'<\/textarea>');"
              + "console.log(clone);"
              + "var file = new Blob([clone], {'type':'text/html'});"
              + "a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);"
              + "a.download = 'file-' + new Date().getTime() + '.html';"
              + "a.click();"
              + "};"
              + "</scr"+"ipt>"
              + "</body>"
              + "</html>"];

  var file = new Blob([clone], {"type":"text/html"});  
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = "file-" + new Date().getTime() + ".html";
  a.click();  

};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly and simply what *should* be happening vs what is actually occurring? Maybe give some better context on the overall concept as well?

Comment: @Anthony Expected result is saved file following `click` on "save file" `button` , when opened , should render text input into `textarea` element from previous `html` document , including sibling `button` element. Context is attempt to create self-modifying , pseudo-polymorphic `html` document , where changes made at `textarea` , saved at one version , rendered at next saved version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replace function replaces until the `/textarea>` that is in your `clone` variable. It doesn't do it from the first file because there's a newline character after textarea in the html. One way to fix it would be to add a `newline` character in the generated html. Like this:

```
var clone = ["<!doctype html><head></head><body><textarea>"
          + input.value
         // add newline here
          + "</textarea>\n"
          + "<button>save file</button>"
          + "<script type='text/javascript'>"
          + "var saveFile = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];"
          + "var input = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];"
          + "var a = document.createElement('a');"
          + "saveFile.onclick = function(e) {"
          + "var clone = '<!doctype html>'+ document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(/<textarea>.*<.+textarea>/, '<textarea>'+document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value+'<\/textarea>');"
          + "console.log(clone);"
          + "var file = new Blob([clone], {'type':'text/html'});"
          + "a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);"
          + "a.download = 'file-' + new Date().getTime() + '.html';"
          + "a.click();"
          + "};"
          + "</scr"+"ipt>"
          + "</body>"
          + "</html>"];
```

Comment: Tried `+ '</textarea>\n');"` , `button` was displayed , though appeared to render new line at `js` ; next line beginning with `');console.log(clone)` rendered as text string , not `js` at source.

Comment: see edit, you need to add \n after first "</textarea>"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is breaking the third-generation clone so that it results in the js info being output to the page, but it would probably be better to use an actual document object to clone/manipulate the original and output its contents as string for the `Blob` object. For example, I tested using your base saveFile.html with the following changes:

```
//remove original clone var and replace with:
var clone = document.cloneNode(true);

// grab textarea elements from both original document and clone:
var doc_input = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
var clone_input = clone.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

// set clone textarea's innerHTML to current textarea value:
clone_input.innerHTML = doc_input.value;

// use outerHTML of clone.documentElement to get string for Blob
var clone_string = [clone.documentElement.outerHTML];
var file = new Blob([clone_string], {"type":"text/html"});
```

The only downsides I am seeing are:

1. This may be hard to expand into a more generic framework for generating a "live HTML file" of current state of loaded HTML page (though it shouldn't be more complicated than your example approach).
2. The string returned by `clone.documentElement.outerHTML` appears to drop the document type declaration to a simple element so that :

is not in the output string. You could probably use something like:

```
var clone_string = ["<!doctype html>" + clone.documentElement.outerHTML];
```

as a workaround. Or, for something more robust:

```
var doc_doctype = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype);

var clone_string = [doc_doctype + clone.documentElement.outerHTML];
```

Comment: Updated. Also added a v2 of the html that just uses `serializeToString` instead of `outerHTML`. Make sure that you test against any browsers you want it to work with.