# Download a string as .txt file in React

Tags: javascript, file, reactjs, mime-types

I have a string which needs to be downloaded in a `txt` file when click on a button. How can this be implemented using React?

Comment: What is your setup?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Here's a working example. Enter the text in the input field and click <kbd>Download txt</kbd>, this will download a `txt` with the contents you entered in the input.

This solution creates a new [**Blob object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) of the `text` MIME type and attaches it to the `href` of a temporary anchor (`<a>`) element which is then triggered programmatically.

> A Blob object represents a file-like object of immutable, raw data. Blobs represent data that isn't necessarily in a JavaScript-native format.

---

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  downloadTxtFile = () => {
    const element = document.createElement("a");
    const file = new Blob([document.getElementById('myInput').value], {type: 'text/plain'});
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "myFile.txt";
    document.body.appendChild(element); // Required for this to work in FireFox
    element.click();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input id="myInput" />
        <button onClick={this.downloadTxtFile}>Download txt</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("myApp"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp"></div>
```

*This answer was derived from [thanhpk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2646539/thanhpk) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35548142/2030321).*

Comment: so, what you're actually saying is this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB, not really. The linked question does not explain the solution, nor is it a question related to react. Marking this as a dupe to that question would not be very helpful to OP nor to future readers. I explain the solution and provide a working sample, which is more helpful than said post. But why don't you mark it as a dupe yourself if you think it is?

Comment: i was debating on closing it in the opposite direction. as you said, this is a much more useful QA pair.

Comment: For some reason this code does nothing in Firefox for me(

Comment: Firefox requires the element to be appended to the body before the click. 

document.body.appendChild(element)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this fast solution, but it fails for me for large string of text, the Click handler in chrome fails.

Comment: for me its working with Incognito mode but not working in normal mode using chrome, any suggestion?

Comment: @AbhishekTomar where did you try this? on your own website?

Comment: Yes; trying on my own site using localhost.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Can confirm this still works as of 2023.

Answer (score 2):

For using React with hooks and arrow functions, here's a working example:

```
const DownloadButton = ({textOutput}: { textOutput: string }) => {
    const file = new Blob([textOutput], {type: 'text/plain'});

    return (
            <Button variant="outlined">
                <a download="sample.txt" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href={URL.createObjectURL(file)} style={{
                    textDecoration: "inherit",
                    color: "inherit",
                }}>Download</a>
            </Button>
    )
}
```

Note: I'm using MUI lib and added some styling to make sure anchor tag dont mess with the styling.