# Creating .eml file from dynamic web components (React/Vue/Angular) [string of compiled html]

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, vue.js, eml

The title may be confusing, so let me expand a little more:

My goal is to have a front end framework/(library), like React, Vue, or Angular, that has a normal user interface stuff, such as the user inputting data or an uploading an image to a server.

I then want the web app to basically make an HTML email. So, I'm thinking the best way is to create a text file of HTML, but it will be of the format `.eml` instead of .txt so it's easy to open in mail clients and send the email.

My question: 
- **How can I create a string of dynamic HTML that is then saved as a file for the user to download.** *dynamic meaning sometimes it may be just 1 or 2 items, sometimes it may be 15, but the point is that the variable will change and a loop will be run for as many objects as there are so that the appropriate amount of HTML will be created.*

I'm asking because we all know how to display a `view` in React/others, but how can we get a programmatic pseudo-view in the logic code. *That is, how do we get a string representation of the views output of the resulting html*, if that makes sense. And then create an `.eml` file holding that html so the user can download.

Is this even possible in the operations of today's popular frameworks?

====

**EDIT**

Just an idea I had from research, for generating the file it seems a `Blob` might be best.

```
var file = new Blob([html_string], {type: 'text/plain'})
```

Some, for React, some code would be like the following (thanks to Chris's answer from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656610/download-a-string-as-txt-file-in-react).)

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
_downloadTxtFile = () => {
    var element = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([document.getElementById('myInput').value], {type: 'text/plain'});
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "myFile.txt";
    element.click();
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <input id="myInput" />
        <button onClick={this._downloadTxtFile}>Download txt</button>
    </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("myApp"));
```

**Which leaves the question** of how to create the string of HTML. Maybe ES6 template literals with embedded expressions? But, that wouldn't be JSX exactly, so I'm not sure how to throw a `for` loop in there. I'll continue researching or if someone knows how to throw all this together.