# Save input from html to text file problem

Tags: javascript, html, database, web, backend

So, I've copied this code and tried to run it. It supposed to take the input (in this case, name) and save it into a  text file. But, it didn't work as I expected, can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
<!DOCTPYE html>

<head>
<title>Web test</title>
</head>

<body>
<form onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
    <label>Name please: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nname" id="fname" size="18">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
<script>
    function WriteToFile(passForm){
    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    set s = fso.CeateTextFile("test.txt", True);
    var firstName = document.getElementById('fname');
    s.writeline(firstName);
    s.writeline("");
    s.Close();
    }
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: This way is no longer work. Try using `Blob` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35548142/13396863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a misspelling here `var firstName = document.geteElementById('fname');` it's supposed to be `var firstName = document.getElementById('fname');`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the misspelling right after I posted this question, but it is still not working after I changed it

Comment: it's supposed to be var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value; try changing it back