# Save HTML to file

Tags: jquery, html, file, save, clone

I am using clone to generate new divs in my html, what would be a good way to save the whole html(that was edited by the user), to a FILE, I won't be using this in a server side,
I want to save the cloned information and reload with the changes, I found this line below, but I don't know how to save the clone html to a file (or the same file) and if it will work.

```
 var $alteredHtml = $('html').clone();
```

Comment: take the outerHTML and send to server with ajax

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/30563157/

Answer (score -1):

There is something in Javascript called `Blob`. Using this you can create a downloadable file of various data types.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob