# New File stucks

Tags: javascript, file

I am new in javascript and was trying to read and write in local txt file so I did as I found in the web but for some reason it stucks in new File instantiation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var txtFile = "d:/test.txt"
alert('point 1');
var file = new File(txtFile);
alert('point 2');
</script>
```

It prints only 'point 1' string. Thanks.

Comment: `File` constructor requires two parameters

Comment: Writing to the local file system is much more complicated than that. Look up some tutorials!

Comment: I was not saying that I was trying to write in a file in this particular piece of code, I was saying that it stucks in the new file instantiation, this is first part, understand a phrase is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2):

[`new File()`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file) constructor requires at least two parameters; first parameter an array containing `String`, `ArrayBufferView`, `ArrayBuffer` `Blob` or another `File` object; the second the file name. You cannot specify a download directory for files using `javascript`, but you can set a download directory at browser settings or preferences. You can also utilize `download` attribute at `a` element to set file name at `Save File` dialog.

> I am new in javascript and was trying to read and write in local txt
>   file

You could use `<input type="file">` element to retrieve `test.txt`, and edit `.txt` file at `<textarea>` before re-saving with same file name. See also [Edit, save, self-modifying HTML document; format generated HTML, JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563157/edit-save-self-modifying-html-document-format-generated-html-javascript) , [How to Write in file (user directory) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098129/how-to-write-in-file-user-directory-using-javascript/)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var txtFile = "test.txt";
  var text = "abc";
  var file = new File([text], txtFile);
  console.log(file);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = file.name;
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.innerHTML = file.name;
  a.onclick = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It generates one file with the text and erases every text if the file exists, but how to recover the text to an string?

Comment: @JamesB _"It generates one file with the text and erases every text if the file exists, but how to recover the text to an string?"_ Aru trying to concatenate additional text content to existing file, then save file?

Comment: Sorry you don't understand, you code create a file and the link to download it, I want to read and write in local machine.

Comment: @JamesB _"I want to read and write in local machine"_ This is the closest have been able to achieve to direct read and write in local machine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098129/how-to-write-in-file-user-directory-using-javascript/ . Note, when a file is downloaded, it is written to local machine. You could use `<input type="file"/>` to read file from local machine, modify file, then download file set to same name to overwrite existing file see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563157/edit-save-self-modifying-html-document-format-generated-html-javascript