# How to store a value from an HTML input field in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I would like to know how to store a value from an HTML input field after a button is clicked into a JavaScript array **and then** how to display that array data to the screen.

Thank you, below is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Checklist</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  

    <input type="text" id="item" placeholder="Enter an item">
    <button id="add">Add Item</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. Yes I changed it.

Comment: @user3278038 Do you want to update the same file, or create a new file at each save?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I changed the question from storing data into a JSON file, to, an array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  create an array, at click of `button`, push `input type="text"` element value to array; use `window.open()` `data URI` of type `application/octet-stream` to download file. To update existing file, you can include `<input type="file">` element for user to upload same file which was downloaded, push current `input type="text"` value to same file, then prompt user to download original file with same name. Though note, it is user decision to download file.

See also [Edit, save, self-modifying HTML document; format generated HTML, JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563157/edit-save-self-modifying-html-document-format-generated-html-javascript)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Checklist</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var input = $(":text");
      var button = $("button");
      var arr = [];
      button.click(function() {
        arr.push(input.val());
        input.val("");
        window.open("data:application/octet-stream," + JSON.stringify(arr));

      })
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>  

    <input type="text" id="item" name="save" placeholder="Enter an item">
    <button id="add">Add Item</button>

</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/cQZznvyltX46UO1Y0lDG?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question from saving into a file, to, into an array.

Comment: @user3278038 Yes, `javascript` at post achieves this. You can remove `window.open("data:application/octet-stream," + JSON.stringify(arr));` portion. `arr` should contain value of `#item` element pushed to `arr` array at each click on `button` element

Comment: @user3278038 See updated plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/cQZznvyltX46UO1Y0lDG?p=preview

Comment: this is great! How can it be changed to display each item in the array inside of an HTML list? Thanks.

Comment: @user3278038 _"How can it be changed to display each item in the array inside of an HTML list?"_ You can append the item in the array to the list item