# How can I read an svg file included in my project and write to it?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a sample svg file (let's call it "myImage.svg") as code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg>
  <g>
    <rect
       style="fill:#ff8080;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect3336"
       width="100"
       height="10"
       x="0"
       y="412.36221" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

It is included in my project's directory.

In another JavaScript file, I would like to do something like this:

```
var file = getFile("myImage.svg");
var rect = file.getElement("rect");
rect.getAttribute("width") = "1000";
```

I've read many questions on StackOverflow but I'm at a loss at where to start to get my file.

Comment: Is expected result to load, change and save file with same file name locally, or at server?

Comment: @guest271314 locally is fine. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()`, `DOMParser()`, `String.prototype.indexOf()`, `String.prototype.slice()`, `<a>` element, `download` attribute at `<a>` element, `encodeURIComponent()`

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "myImage.svg");
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml");
  request.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    var response = event.target.responseText;
    var doc = new DOMParser();
    var xml = doc.parseFromString(response, "image/svg+xml");
    var rect = xml.getElementById("rect3336");
    rect.setAttribute("width", 1000);
    var result = response.slice(0, response.indexOf("<svg"));
    result += xml.documentElement.outerHTML;
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "myImage.svg";
    a.href = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(result);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  });
  request.send();
```

Comment: @ravp See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563157/edit-save-self-modifying-html-document-format-generated-html-javascript

Comment: You shouldn't have to use a get request to simply read/write files locally.