# Angular Spread Operator not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to process an array in angular. I need to get admin user name from an array and trying below approach

```
export class AppComponent  {
  adminName = ''
  data = {
    id:1,
    name:'Test User One',
    users:[
      {id:1,name:'User 2',role:'Management Admin'},
      {id:2,name:'User 3',role:'User'},
      {id:3,name:'User 1',role:'Profile Admin'},
    ]
  }

  ngOnInit(){
     this.getAdminName(this.data.users)
  }

  getAdminName(users){
   let name = ''
    name = users.filter((user)=>{
      user.role = user.role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()
      return user.role === 'PROFILE-ADMIN'
    }).map(row=>{
      return row.name
    })
    this.adminName = name[0]
  }
}
```

This is working and i am able to get **adminName** but it also changes role of data object and converts object like this

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test User One",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "User 2",
      "role": "MANAGEMENT-ADMIN"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "User 3",
      "role": "USER"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "User 1",
      "role": "PROFILE-ADMIN"
    }
  ]
}
```

I understand why this happened and i tried using spread operator but it is not working i tried below approach

**Approach one**

```
this.getAdminName([...this.data.users]) // passing from here using spread operator
```

**Approach Second**

```
getAdminName(users){
   let usersList = [...users]
   let name = ''
    name = usersList.filter((user)=>{
      user.role = user.role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()
      return user.role === 'PROFILE-ADMIN'
    }).map(row=>{
      return row.name
    })
    this.adminName = name[0]
  }
```

I am able to do it like below

```
getAdminName(users){
   let name = ''
   let role;
    name = users.filter((user)=>{
      role = user.role //used a variable in which holds 
      role = role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()
      return role === 'PROFILE-ADMIN'
    }).map(row=>{
      return row.name
    })
    this.adminName = name[0]
  }
```

But I want to do it using spread Operator approach so Please suggest me where i am going wrong

Stackblitz link is here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjnytr

Comment: `user.role = user.role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()` this will modify the user role. Can you not check without assigining it to `user.role`?

Comment: yes i know and i explained it in my question i am getting issue in creating copy from spread operator only

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use spread syntax? You can filter out any element without changing the data itself. I don't think there is any need to shallow-copy the array first.

Comment: That approach is frankly unnecessary. As long as you use `user.role = user.role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()`, no amount of spread operators will give the desired result

Comment: ok so could you tell me which one will be better this will help me to know right approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change filter logic to avoid any side effects.

```
getAdminName(users) {
  const name = users
    .filter(user => user.role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase() === 'PROFILE-ADMIN')
    .map(row => row.name);

  return name ? name[0] : '';
}
```

This way you do not need to think about how spread operator works.

```
this.getAdminName(this.data.users)
```

Answer (score 2):

`users` is a reference type. So you need to create a deep copy of an object. Try to use `JSON.parse` method to create a deep copy of an object:

```
let usersList = [...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users))]
```

Comment: In this specific case, this may work, but generally, you will lose any functions and non-enumerable properties for your objects using this method of "deep copy" Also, deep copying has been covered in [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/215552) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39968366/215552) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416020/215552)...

Answer (score 0):

In your function, replace the `user.role = user.role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()` by a new variable, this:

```
getAdminName(users){
   let usersList = [...users]
   let name = ''
    name = usersList.filter((user)=>{
      let role = user.role;
      role = role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()
      return role === 'PROFILE-ADMIN'
    }).map(row=>{
      return row.name
    })
    this.adminName = name[0]
  }
```

Comment: This is the same as what the user has in their question, except it has `let` in front of the definition of `role`. Which is great, but...

Answer (score 0):

> **First of all, Spread operation won't work,**

Reason, it's only helpful for single layered data structure, meaning array of primitive data types, for array of objects it dose not create deep copy when nested properties are in picture.

So you should use Lodashs cloneDeep method.

**UPDATED**

> install lodash in your angular project

Then import it like

> import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';
>   Blockquote

and use it like,

```
  getAdminName(users){
   let usersList = cloneDeep(users);
   let name = ''
    name = usersList.filter((user)=>{
      user.role = user.role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()
      return user.role === 'PROFILE-ADMIN'
    }).map(row=>{
      return row.name
    })
    this.adminName = name[0]
  }
```

This should solve your problem here

Comment: Also please upvote me and accept my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? It would give the same results as OP

Comment: You can paste this code there, and verify for yourself

Comment: Such is life..no worries, keep coding and answering :)

Comment: @Indrajeet Your code still modifies the original data (`user.role = user.role.replace(...)`)

Comment: Ohhh, wait I'll give you the answer

Comment: @subarachnid Can you try now, now it won't change the state of original data.

Comment: @Indrajeet, that's true but the cloning is completely unneccessary. The OP just wants to filter out the correct element by `role` and return its `name`. There is really no need to clone anything here.

Comment: Yes, but's it is changing the reference data structure. which is not ideal.

Comment: It does when you reassign user.role like `user.role = user.role...`. But this is not needed at all. See yurzui's answer...

Comment: BTW this was your comment ***@Indrajeet Your code still modifies the original data (user.role = user.role.replace(...)*** 20 mins back that's why I replied 

Comment: *it's only helpful for single layered data structure* Spread operation will work for any number of layers

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava but it does not change the reference for nested properties of objects. I have tried a hundred times in my project . https://bambielli.com/til/2017-01-29-spread-operator-deep-copy/

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator on the array do just that spreads the array. In the way you are using it you are simply passing an equivalent amount of arguments to the getAdmin() method or the userList variable as the elements in the array.

Try something like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.getAdminName(this.data.users)
}

getAdminName(users){
   const adminUser = users.find(({ role }) => {
     role = role.replace(/\s/g, '-').toUpperCase()
     return role === 'PROFILE-ADMIN'
   });
   this.adminName = adminUser.name;
}
```