# Is there any way to post content to a server-side .txt file with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to post content onto another .txt file that I host. I know there is a way to *load* data, but is there a way to save it?

For loading, I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script src=/files/scripts/jquery.js></script><!--i host jquery-->
<script>
jQuery.get('/development/lol.txt',function(data){
  $('body').text(data);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But is there a way I can write data onto a .txt file like how I loaded it?

Comment: `txt` file is a static resource. Must use a server side dynamic programming  language to write to file

Comment: You need to write server side code to accomplish this.

Comment: I would use an Ajax POST request to write to the file.

Comment: @D.Foley that's not exactly helpful

Comment: @phil on my phone at the moment, will write a detailed answer once I get to a computer (assuming it has not been answered).

Comment: Are you trying at `file:` protocol?

Comment: What is your HTTP server (Apache, nginx, IIS, etc)? What server-side applications / languages are available (NodeJS, PHP, python, Java, etc)?

Comment: @guest271314 1) That's unlikely given that `jQuery.get('/development/lol.txt')` presumably works. 2) Why is that relevant?

Comment: @Phil _"1) That's unlikely given that jQuery.get('/development/lol.txt') presumably works."_ The same `javascript` can return same result at `file:` protocol. _"2) Why is that relevant?"_ If `file:` protocol is used, an alternative approach would be to use `<input type="file">`, `html`  to achieve requirement by uploading, editing, saving file to local filesystem [Edit, save, self-modifying HTML document; format generated HTML, JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563157/edit-save-self-modifying-html-document-format-generated-html-javascript)

Comment: jQuery is client side code. You'll need to handle this on the server. What server are you running? Do you have access?

Answer (score 1):

**Note, This is just an example of a concept, there are more details you must take into account in a production environment**

There is limited information about your development environment (i.e web server software, server-side language used). But here is what I would do in the case of a LAMP (linux, apache, mysql, php) setup.

I create a javascript function to handle write to the remote text file:

```
function logOnLoad()
{
    var sData = "Page has been loaded";

    $.ajax({
        url:"https://example.domain.com/logData.php",
        data: {sData: sData},
        method:"post"
    }).done(function()
    {
        alert("Finished Async write to server side file.");
    })
}
```

I then subscribe this function to an event handle (it can be any other event handler though, it's up to you in regards to when you want to write this data), for this example I just use onload on the body tag:

```
<body onload="logOnLoad()">
<p>test</p>

</body>
```

So now my javascript function executes onload of the html page. Now we need to write the server side code to handle the ajax request, so I create a php file called logData.php and put this in the file:

```
<?php

function writeData($sData, $sFilePath)
{
    $sTargetFile = fopen($sFilePath, "a");

    fwrite($sTargetFile, $sData);
    fclose($sTargetFile);
}

if(isset($_POST['sData']))
{
    writeData($_POST['sData'], "testLog.txt");
    echo "done";
}
```

Now whenever I load test.html, it takes the static content from the javascript variable sData and does a POST against the logData.php, the logData.php file in return looks for the file specified in the writeData function call (in this example I look for testLog.txt). It creates a file handle from this information and we do a fwrite($sTargetFile, $sData) and this writes the content to the server side text file.

Comment: i recieve an error `POST https://trialsite10.netlify.app/logData.php 404` . wHAT SHOULD I DO. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: The php file is in the same directory as the htm file... The name of HTML file is : `index.html`, `script.js`, 'logData.php', `testLog.txt`... all the files are in same folder