# How to append a whole html file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a html file like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   //some content
  </head>
  <body>
   //some content
  </body>
 </html>
```

My question is how to load this file as a whole with jquery. I tried it with 
append function, but it didn't work.. I searched for the solution for quite a while, but just found a lot of methods to append some parts of html file, like meta, link, not a whole file.

Can I do it with jquery?

Comment: you can use the .load() method

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to do that? Perhaps your'e asking the wrong question. What's the ultimate goal? Maybe you're going about it wrong.

Comment: I'm making a project with playcanvas, a 3D engine. With this engine,  I have to load html file with document, otherwise it wont show my ui written by html + css. I know a simple way for doing this is to use jquery, but I don't know how to load or append the whole html exactly. This is why I pose this question.

Comment: Where should file be loaded to?

Comment: Please check: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp

Comment: it should goes to the document.

Comment: Please share with us what have you tried and how it didnt work

Comment: Are you trying to replace entire existing `document` with file?

Comment: @guest271314, yes I am

Answer (score 1):

**index.html or whatever**

```
<iframe src="filename.html"></iframe>
```

**filename.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   //some content
  </head>
  <body>
   //some content
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: OP is trying to replace existing `document` with imported `document`, not display imported `document` in `<iframe>` element.

Comment: I thought he was "appending" it which would mean adding it at the end or in a child element etc

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404728/how-to-append-a-whole-html-file-with-jquery/43405004#comment73870071_43404728, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404728/how-to-append-a-whole-html-file-with-jquery/43405004#comment73870107_43404728

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<link>` element with `rel` attribute set to `import`, `href` set to path to file, `type` set to `"text/html"`. Use `XMLSerializer()` instance `.serializeToString()` with replacement `document` `.doctype` property as parameter to get `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration from imported `document`; `document.write()` with `.import.documentElement.outerHTML` property of `link` element as parameter to replace existing `.doctype` and `<html>` node with `.doctype` and `<html>` of imported `document`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <link id="doc" rel="import" href="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/9921cb52b143437b23f23fa32284ca35/raw/86532c043b666bce15b33c91dc29e98615dd4e25/replacementDocument.html" type="text/html" />
  </head>
  <body>
   //original content
   <button>load html document</button>
   <script>
   var link = document.getElementById("doc");
   document.querySelector("button")
   .onclick = function() {
     // http://stackoverflow.com/a/30565562/
     var dt = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(link.import.doctype);  
     document.write(dt, link.import.documentElement.outerHTML);
     document.close();
   }
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox, IE11, or Edge. Appears to work in Chrome.