# How to querySelector an element in an html import from a document that imports it?

Tags: javascript, html

Let say I have a html document with this `div` inside :

*div.html*

```
  <div class="thediv">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p class="insert"></p>
  </div>
```

from *index.html*, I import it

```
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/div.html">
```

Now If I type in the console or in a script

```
const div = document.querySelector('.thediv');
```

`div` is `null`, as if the div just vanished. But I am sure there is a way to select the element because some webcomponents libraries allow programmer to define their own custom elements one by file.

I tried many things but can't find the solution.
Thanks for the help.

**update :**
This is true for any HTML Elements (not just `div`). I just pick an example for the question.

Comment: a `<template>` is overridden with the content. Once the page renders it's not there anymore. You need to address the template's **content** and not the `<template>` tag itself.

Comment: @KobyDouek Can you consider making an answer ticket ? I don't quite catch the idea but I'm sure this is interesting informations. Thanks

Comment: @KobyDouek My question applies to every html elements (not just `template`), I was just picking an example.

Comment: I applied an answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, I rewrite all the code because I originally used `template` and people were confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the `document` set at `<link>` element with `rel` attribute set to `"import"` using `.import` property of `<link>` element, see also [Is there a way to know if a link/script is still pending or has it failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824927/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-link-script-is-still-pending-or-has-it-failed/39908873?s=4|3.0036#39908873), [How to append a whole html file with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404728/how-to-append-a-whole-html-file-with-jquery/43405004#43405004)

```
document.querySelector("link[rel=import][href='template1.html']")
.import.querySelector("#template1")
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a solution, I was hoping that every imports were contained in a common object or something because let say I need to `querySelector` an element in a html import that were imported from another html import, I need to go through the whole import tree just to select it, this is a bit cumbersome. But thanks

Comment: `.import` references a `document` object. How the HTML or other document type is composed is left to the author of the `document`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

import.html

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <!-- Img is not requested until the <template> goes live. -->
  <img src="world.png">
  <script>alert("Executed when the template is activated.");</script>
</template>
```

index.html

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="import.html">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');

    // Clone the <template> in the import.
    var template = link.import.querySelector('template');
    var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(clone);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The link you referred to helped me to find a suitable solution for my case, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 nice answers on my question and they helped me to find a more suitable solution for my specific problem I'm sharing here.
Again what I tried to achieve was to `querySelector` an element defined in an html import from the main document (i.e. `index.html`).
If we write something like

```
<div id="thediv">
  ...
</div>
```

at the root of an html import, the element won't be included in the body of the main document (I think each document has its own namespace or something like that).

**@guest271314** recommended to use the `import` property of a `link` element to access the content of the fetched resource but *see my comment* on the same post. I think this is not really neat when you deal with documents that imports other documents that imports others...
**@MaxBilbow** recommended the same method providing a link and an example chunk using `template`. Again this is not really nice when you deal with relational imports. But the link gave me the solution.

In my imported document, I write an additional script :

*div.html*

```
<div id="thediv">
  ...
</div>

<script>
document.body.prepend(
   document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#thediv'));
</script>
```

Now when the html import is fetched the script will get executed and prepend the html chunk into the `body` of the main document.

*index.html*

```
<link rel="import" href="div.html">

<script>
// now I can querySelector('#thediv')
</script>
```

This is just an example and it is a dummy one, but I think I will mostly use that technique for templates, templates are hidden and it's ok to prepend them to the main document.

If you think that method could have flaws, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Imports is deprecated and has now been removed as of M80. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 and https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/07/web-components-time-to-upgrade for more details.

You ca use `fetch()` to import your web component
[How to separate web components to individual files and load them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080103/how-to-separate-web-components-to-individual-files-and-load-them/55081177#55081177)