# Separation of Concerns in Web Components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

In every web component tutorial I see people building their custom elements just putting HTML and CSS inside JS (as a string value to an object property). What makes me wonder: Is there a way to make web components without mixing layout, style and behavior like that?

Being more specific, is it possible to build a web component separating the code into three files (.html, .css and .js)? Or even making a single file, but having the code split into three tags (`<template>`, `<style>` and `<script>`)?

Comment: Have you tried creating a **single** file with the 3 tags you mentioned?

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for HTML modules, and CSS module scripts to land in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [How to separate web components to individual files and load them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080103/how-to-separate-web-components-to-individual-files-and-load-them)

Here the author of the accepted answer proposed creating a javascript file that uses `fetch()` to load the HTML source code for the component. Then inside the HTML file link the separate CSS file using `<link rel="stylesheet">`

Inside your main HTML file you can then import the script that you create in the first step to load the web component.

This is just a summary, i invite you to check it out by yourself :) Cheers